# What does "-c" mean in this linux shell command?

Tags: python, debian

It's from a tutorial on the google cloud platform, they call python from the Linux Shell.
I'm totally new to gcp and linux, please help me, where can I find some exhaustive documentation for python tools in Linux?

```
python -c 'import base64, sys, json; \
  img = base64.b64encode(open(sys.argv[1], "rb").read()); \
  print json.dumps({"key":"1", "image_bytes": {"b64": img}})' \
  flower1.jpg > request.json
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 3):

-c stand for cmd which allows you to pass your code as a string.
This feature is available even outside of google-cloud-platform.
you can check other available options using python -h

Answer (score 2):

the -c flag means execute the following command as interpreted by this program.

Doc: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831847/what-is-the-sh-c-command

Answer (score 1):

When called with -c command, it executes the Python statement(s) given as command. Here command may contain multiple statements separated by newlines. Leading whitespace is significant in Python statements!